# How to import a message with the Gmail API in Java

Tags: android, gmail-api

I've studied this page:
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/import

I have some messages I will be keeping track of in my Android program. I will be keeping a record of the messages I will be deleting and I would like to import those messages slated for deletion into a new folder (In Gmail API folders are called Labels).

I tried the test form:

```
            POST https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/omitted%40gmail.com/messages/import?deleted=false&internalDateSource=dateHeader&neverMarkSpam=true&processForCalendar=false&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
            {
             "payload": {
              "body": {
               "data": "hellio"
              }
             }
            }
```

Response:

```
        400 OK
        - SHOW HEADERS -
        {
         "error": {
          "errors": [
           {
            "domain": "global",
            "reason": "invalidArgument",
            "message": "'raw' RFC822 payload message string or uploading message via /upload/* URL required"
           }
          ],
          "code": 400,
          "message": "'raw' RFC822 payload message string or uploading message via /upload/* URL required"
         }
        }
```

There is a problem sending the request but I am not sure at all what it means. What I need is some Java that sends a request that will import a message where I can specify the body, received date and subject line. Is it possible?

Thank you.

P.S. I just wanted to delete the attachments not the whole message but after reading the Gmail API documents it looks like this is not possible and is only possible through IMAP. The reason I am asking this question is so that I don't have to move my whole program to IMAP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pretty close with your code. What you need to do is write a mail compliant with the [RFC 2822 standard](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2822.html), and Base64-encode said mail and make it URL-safe (replace all `+` with `-` and all `/` with `_`) before inserting it.

You are better at Java than me, but if I would make a correct message in the browser's Developer Console, it could look something like this:

```
var encodedMail = btoa(
  "Date: Thu, 1 Jan 1970 12:00:00 -0000\n" +
  "From: emtholin@gmail.com\n" +
  "To: emtholin@gmail.com\n" +
  "Subject: Example Subject\n\n" +

  "This is the body of the mail"
).replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_');
```

Then I just insert this mail with the same request you issued:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?internalDateSource=dateHeader&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

{
 "raw": "RGF0ZTogVGh1LCAxIEphbiAxOTcwIDEyOjAwOjAwIC0wMDAwCkZyb206IGVtdGhvbGluQGdtYWlsLmNvbQpUbzogZW10aG9saW5AZ21haWwuY29tClN1YmplY3Q6IEV4YW1wbGUgU3ViamVjdAoKVGhpcyBpcyB0aGUgYm9keSBvZiB0aGUgbWFpbA=="
}
```

As you can see, this worked great!

[image]